# Problems trying to restart my tic tac toe program

Tags: java

For some reason when i ask if the user wants to play again if they say yes it will just say who won and if they say no it works fine and exits the program.

I am just looking to see what the problem is. I am not trying to be pushy and see if anyone can fix the code. I have been trying to fix it for hours any suggestions help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;/*
Program8C Tic Tac Toe  made by Daniel Underwood on 1/31/18.
This program plays tic tac toe with no graphics but does detect who has 
won
*/
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program8C {
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// method generates the matrix
public static void printMatrix(char[][] matrix) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

//method checks to see if the user input valid
public static boolean isUserInputValid(int userInt) {
    if (userInt >= 0 && userInt < 3)
        return true;
    else {
        System.out.println("Must be between 0 and 2.");
        return false;
    }

}
public static boolean isFull(char[][] matrix){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == ' ') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The game is over, The Cat won");
    return true;
}

//method detects when the game is finished
private static boolean isGameOver(char whoseTurn, char[][] matrix) {
    boolean won = false;
    boolean cat = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (matrix[i][0] == whoseTurn
                && matrix[i][1] ==whoseTurn
                && matrix[i][2] == whoseTurn){
            won = true;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (matrix[0][j] == whoseTurn
                    && matrix[1][j] == whoseTurn
                    && matrix[2][j] == whoseTurn) {
                won = true;
            }
        }
        if (matrix[0][0] == whoseTurn
                && matrix[1][1] == whoseTurn
                && matrix[2][2] == whoseTurn) {
            won = true;
        }
        if (matrix[0][2] == whoseTurn
                && matrix[1][1] == whoseTurn
                && matrix[2][0] == whoseTurn){
            won = true;
        }
    }
    if (won) {
        System.out.printf("%c WON!!!", whoseTurn);
        return true;
    }
    if (cat){
        System.out.println("Cat has won");
    }
        return false;

}


private static boolean takeTurn(char whoseTurn, char[][] matrix) {
    // takeTurn accepts a char which is X or O indicating whose takeTurn it is.
    // we return a boolean that indicates whether the game is over or not.
    int answer;
    int userRow = 0;
    int userCol = 0;
    boolean userInputCorrect = false;
    boolean locationError = false;

    do {
        // get whoseTurn's next move
        System.out.printf("It's %c's takeTurn.", whoseTurn);
        System.out.println(" ");
        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter row(must be between 0 and 2): ");
            userRow = input.nextInt();
            userInputCorrect = isUserInputValid(userRow);

        } while (!userInputCorrect);
        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter column(must be between 0 and 2): ");
            userCol = input.nextInt();
            userInputCorrect = isUserInputValid(userCol);

        } while (!userInputCorrect);
        //if statement

        if (matrix[userRow][userCol] == ' ') {
            matrix[userRow][userCol] = whoseTurn;
            locationError = false;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Location is already taken please select another location");
            locationError = true;
        }
    }
    while (locationError);

    printMatrix(matrix);

    if(isFull(matrix) || isGameOver(whoseTurn, matrix)){
        System.out.println(" Would you like to play again(1 for yes or 2 for No):");
        answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer == 1){
            new Program8C();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing. Come back soon.");
        }
    }
        return isGameOver(whoseTurn, matrix);
    }

// main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] matrix = {
            {' ', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', ' '}
    };
    boolean done = false;
    char whoseTurn = 'X';

    printMatrix(matrix);

    do {
        //changes whose turn it is
        done = takeTurn(whoseTurn, matrix);
        if (whoseTurn == 'X')
            whoseTurn = 'O';
        else
            whoseTurn = 'X';
    } while (!done);

}
}
```

Comment: do not `return isGameOver(...);`, instead, only `return true;` when the user does not want to play anymore, and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the game is over, you should take input from the user asking to play again. You can take a variable and record user input in this variable. If user says yes, store true else false and do this while variable is true.

Have a look at the following code.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean playAgain = true;
while(playAgain){
    matrix = clearBoard(matrix);
    do {
        //changes whose turn it is
        done = takeTurn(whoseTurn, matrix);
        if (whoseTurn == 'X')
            whoseTurn = 'O';
        else
            whoseTurn = 'X';
        } while (!done);
    String userInput = in.next();
    if(userInput.equals("Yes"))
        playAgain = true;
    else
        playAgain = false;
}
```

call this method to clear the board.

```
public char[][] clearBoard(char[][] board){
    return {
            {' ', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', ' '}
    };
}
```

Comment: I have a statement that ask the user to put 1 for yes or 2 for no and when someone enters 2 it does what it's suppose to do but when someone types a 1 if just repeat's who won

Comment: Update I got it to continue the game but it doesn't clear the board